AvroReader after migrating from 1.11.4 to 1.22
I've just migrated from Nifi 1.11.4 to Nifi 1.22, pretty big jump i know. I face some issue with controllers. With regards to AvroReader 1.11.4 i could specify values for schema name and schema text as shown below:

Nevertheless in 1.22 i do not see such options:

How should i deal with that in a way by keep using schema name & schema text?

We also recently migrated NiFi from 1.9 to 1.28!
Faced similar issue for reader services. Need to tweak a little bit to make this work. In earlier versions, the Reader service properties were redundant, eg. if Schema Access Strategy is set to Use Embedded Avro Schema then doesn't matter if we specify Schema Name or Schema Text values since ultimately schema will be derived from FlowFile content. So with new versions, it is just hiding unrelated properties.
You can apply the same thoughts here - check what is your Schema Access Strategy in Nifi 1.11.4 and then reconfigure 1.22 accordingly. In your screenshot, it is Use Embedded Avro Schema so even with missing schema text or name property, FlowFile will get validated by referencing schema from FlowFile.

So u mean in those processors I need to even remove schema name ?

Yes, if your schema access strategy is Use Embedded Avro Schema then schema will be derived from the FlowFile content since those are in Avro format, so the schema name will not be used though you are passing from processor to reader service. Give it a try, you will understand it!
